# Mean value theorem proof problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose f is defined and differential for every $x>0$ and $f'(x)\rightarrow 0$ while $x\rightarrow \infty$

$g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$
Prove that $g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

I am curious if this proof is correct.

---

First we make $\epsilon >0$

$f'(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow\infty$ means $\exists M  \in \mathbb{R}$

such that $x\ge M$ then $f'(x)<\epsilon$

Now for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $M<a<b$ the mean value theorem says there is an $x \in (a,b)$ such that

$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(x)$

and $x\in(a,b)$ implies that $x>M$ so then

$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(x)<\epsilon$

so then if we let $b=a+1$ we have

$f(a+1)-f(a)=(a+1)-a)f'(x)=f'(x)$

so then if $a>m$

$g(a)=f(a+1)-f(a)=f'(x)<\epsilon$

$g(a)<\epsilon$

and then

$lim :g(x)=lim :f'(k)=0$

where $k\in(x,x+1)$

$x \rightarrow \infty$

END PROOF

Comment: oh sorry forgot that

Comment: I will edit my post

Comment: The proof as written should have ended at $g(a)\lt \epsilon$.  Also, you need absolute values.lots of places.  You need to show that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is an $M$ such that if $a\gt M$ then $|g(a)|\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: But why do I need absolute value, I am not sure

Comment: The function may be negative, or off and on negative. To show that the limit of $g(x)$ is $0$, you need to show that for large enough $x$ we have $|g(x)-0|\lt \epsilon$.